# AngularJS : Animate Slide

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a carousel, in which I would be loading data lazily.
What I want is, when I add a new set of data, it should slide in a normal carousel.

I tried playing with angular-animate and tried adding .enter, .leave css transition
but it does not works

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/93k5A/1/)
css

```
.animate-enter {
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all; /* Chrome */
    transition: 1s linear all;
    opacity: 0;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div ng-repeat="slide in slides"
          ng-animate=" 'animate' " >
             <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="float:left; padding: 10px;"></img>
    </div>
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? 1.2+ made significant changes to animation.

Comment: Angular JS version - 1.2.14

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.2+ uses a different syntax - it's like this:

```
<div class="animate" ng-repeat="slide in slides">
```

You also need to change your css to something like this:

```
.animate.ng-enter, 
.animate.ng-leave
{ 
    -webkit-transition: 1s linear all; /* Chrome */
    transition: 1s linear all;
    opacity: 0;
}
.animate.ng-leave.animate.ng-leave-active,
.animate.ng-enter {
    opacity: 1;
}
.animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active, 
.animate.ng-leave {
    opacity: 0;

}
```

[fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/rapsac/37zs8/)
I haven't got the animation quite working smoothly yet (it's a bit jerky) but you can fiddle with that now that it's actually animating.